Proving that the intersection of kernels is the span of two vectors

Let $l_2$ equiped with $\lVert (v_k) \rVert = (\sum_{k \geq 1} |v_k|^2)^{1/2}$. Consider $\{e_k\}$ the canonical basis and the vectors $x_k= e_k -5e_{k+1} + 6e_{k+2}$ . Prove that for every $z=(z_k) \in l_2$, the following are equivalent: 
(1) $z$ is orthogonal to $M=\operatorname{span}\{x_k\}_{k \in \Bbb{N}}$ 
(2) For all $k \in \Bbb{N}$: $z_k - 5z_{k+1} + 6z_{k+2}=0$ 
(3) $z \in \operatorname{span}\{v_1, v_2\}$ with $v_1 = \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}e_k$ and $v_2 = \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{1}{3^{k-1}}e_k$

I am trying to prove this excercise I found on my Functional analysis book but I am struggling proving $(2) \implies (3)$
I have tried it by defining $f_k : l_2 \rightarrow \Bbb{K}, f_k(z) = z_k - 5z_{k+1} + 6z_{k+2}$ . Then, every $f_k \in l_2'$ and $(2)$ is equivalent to $z \in \cap_{k \geq 1} \ker f_k$. I thought that this would help since there are theorems that relate $\ker$ of functionals and orthogonality, but I am not getting it, so any possible help would be appreciated.

If you think about condition (2) as an (infinite) system of linear equations
\begin{align*}
z_1-5z_2+6z_3\hphantom{-5z_4+6z_5}&=0\\
z_2-5z_3+6z_4\hphantom{+6z_5}&=0\\
z_3-5z_4+6z_5&=0\\
\vdots\quad&\hphantom{=0}\vdots
\end{align*}
a vector $z\in\ell^2$ has to satisfy, then you see that there are exactly two degrees of freedom: e.g., $z_1,z_2$ can be chosen freely, but once they are specificed all other components of $z$ are automatically determined. Thus the set of solutions of these equations form an at most${}^1$ $2$-dimensional subspace of $\ell^2$.

1: "at most" because it could be that certain solutions are not in $\ell^2$. That's where the vectors $v_1,v_2$ come into play for which you have to verify explicitly that they are (i) elements of $\ell^2$ which (ii) are solutions to the above problem.
